# can't blend gradient colors with a stream

Tags: plotting, style, textures

The following function generates a plot of the 3d function indicated in the example.

```
Plot3D[(x^2 + y^2) Exp[1 - x^2 - y^2], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, 
 Mesh -> None, ImageSize -> Large, PlotPoints -> 35, 
 PlotStyle -> {Texture[
    StreamPlot[
     Evaluate[-D[(x^2 + y^2) Exp[1 - x^2 - y^2], {{x, y}}]], {x, -3, 
      3}, {y, -3, 3}, Frame -> None, ImageSize -> Large, 
     StreamStyle -> Black]]}]
```

However, when I choose a different ColorFunction parameter the texture (that only consists of arrows) disappears. Any idea how to correct this? I tried to make the background transparent, combine two 3D plots etc without success. Also, I have no idea why this is happening.

Here is the 3D plot without the gradient field.

```
Plot3D[(x^2 + y^2) Exp[1 - x^2 - y^2], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, 
 Mesh -> None, ImageSize -> Large, PlotPoints -> 35, 
 PlotStyle -> {Texture[
    StreamPlot[
     Evaluate[-D[(x^2 + y^2) Exp[1 - x^2 - y^2], {{x, y}}]], {x, -3, 
      3}, {y, -3, 3}, Frame -> None, ImageSize -> Large, 
     StreamStyle -> Black]]}, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow"]
```

Answer (score 9):

The color is not quite right but the idea seems to work. *Edit: much closer now.*

```
dp = DensityPlot[(x^2 + y^2) Exp[1 - x^2 - y^2], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, 
   ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", PlotPoints -> 100];

sp = StreamPlot[
   Evaluate[-D[(x^2 + y^2) Exp[1 - x^2 - y^2], {{x, y}}]], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, 
   Frame -> None, ImageSize -> Large, StreamStyle -> Black];

tex = Show[dp, sp, Frame -> None, PlotRangePadding -> 0, ImageSize -> 500];

Plot3D[(x^2 + y^2) Exp[1 - x^2 - y^2], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, Mesh -> None, 
 ImageSize -> Large, PlotPoints -> 35
 , PlotStyle -> {Texture[Lighter[tex, 0.15]]}
 , Lighting -> "Neutral"
]
```

[image]

Answer (score 8):

You can use `StreamDensityPlot` (which accepts  the `ColorFunction` option) to produce the texture:

```
sdp = StreamDensityPlot[Evaluate[{-D[(x^2 + y^2) Exp[1 - x^2 - y^2], {{x, y}}], 
    (x^2 + y^2) Exp[1 - x^2 - y^2]}], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, 
   StreamStyle -> Black, 
   ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", 
   ColorFunctionScaling -> False, Frame -> False, Axes -> False, 
   PlotRangePadding -> None];
Plot3D[(x^2 + y^2) Exp[1 - x^2 - y^2], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, 
 Mesh -> None, ImageSize -> Large, PlotPoints -> 35, 
 PlotStyle -> Texture[Lighter@sdp], Lighting -> "Neutral"]
```

[image]

Comment: Slightly shorter: `sdp = StreamDensityPlot[
   Evaluate[{-D[#, {{x, y}}], #} &[(x^2 + y^2) Exp[
       1 - x^2 - y^2]]], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, StreamStyle -> Black,
    ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", Frame -> False, Axes -> False, 
   PlotRangePadding -> None];`

Comment: @MichaelE2, I tried that version; but the colors do not match the colors in Plot3D.

Comment: Odd, they match your code above, for me.  I switched between the two images and saw no (perceptible) difference.

Comment: @MichaelE2, maybe version/os difference (i am using v 11.3 windows 10/64bit).

Comment: @MichaelE2, `ColorFunction -> "Rainbow"` does work if the first argument of `StreamDensityPlot`  has  the form $\{\{v_x, v_y\}, s \}$.

Comment: Yes, that was the main change, which means one can use a simplified `ColorFunction`.  (Perhaps you missed that I had changed the first argument, too.)

Comment: @MichaelE2, i just noticed  the `#` now:)

Answer (score 2):

`PlotStyle -> Texture[...]` relies on `VertexTextureCoordinates` to map the texture to polygon vertices.

`ColorFunction -> colorfunction` relies on `VertexColors` to associate colors with the polygon vertices.

Only one of them actually gets to style the polygon.  In my case, it seems to be the texture:

```
Graphics3D[{Texture[RandomImage[1, 100]], 
  Polygon[{{0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 0}}, 
   VertexColors -> {Red, Green, Blue}, 
   VertexTextureCoordinates -> {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}}]}, 
 Lighting -> "Neutral", BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}]
```

[image]

It sounds like the color function is winning in your case.  It wouldn't surprise me if that was dependent on things like OS, software version, phase of the moon, etc...